# Unit Test - Leafletjs Add Layer / Remove Layer

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, leaflet, react-testing-library

I am looking to create unit tests for the component below to check addLayer and removeLayer being called,

```
function App (()=>{
    const marker = useRef<L.Marker | undefined>( undefined);
    const fg : L.FeatureGroup<any> = fg(); 
    
    useEffect(()=>{
    var myIcon = L.divIcon({className:'my-div-icon',html:renderToStaticMarkup(<ArrowRight/>)});
    marker.current = L.marker([50.5, 30.5], {icon:myIcon});
     if(fg) fg.addLayer(marker.current);
      <div>Text</div>;
    
     return (){
    if(marker.current && fg)
    {fg.removeLayer(marker.current);}
   
    } 
    },[fg]);
    
    });
```

RTL test:

```
const mockAddLayer = jest.fn();
describe("Test Leaflet methods",()=>{
it("Test add Layer",()=>{
const {wrapper} = render (<App/>);
expect(wrapper.getByText('Text')).toBeTruthy();
expect(mockAddLayer).toBeCalled();
});
});
```

The above test is failing with

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()
expected number of calls:  >= 1
received number of calls: 0
```

Is it possible to test fg.addLayer() and fg.removeLayer() are being called?
I am a beginner in unit testing with leafletjs. Any leads are appreciated.